# Quickly delete all floating picture in Excel sheet

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013, photos, selection

I have a lot of photos in my Excel sheet.

I want to delete them all - currently Ctrl-A just select all cells.

How can I select all photo objects?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I find a quick step as below, refered from this [post](http://www.excel-user.com/2010/10/delete-all-pictures-or-charts-on.html)

1. Hit F5 to open `Goto` box
2. Hit `Special
3. Hit `Objects`
4. All photo objects are now selected

We are done.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Quick note - using this way to get all the "objects" may result in grabbing non-shape objects like charts, tables, comments..

Answer (score 3):

Quickly -

1. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to bring up the VBE
2. hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to bring up the immediate window
3. type `activesheet.shapes.selectall`
4. hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
5. Go back to sheet and all will be selected, so you can delete ***OR***
6. If you didn't want to go back to the sheet, just type `selection.delete` and hit enter

Answer (score 1):

You cannot quickly select all floating pictures in an Excel sheet.

But you can do a workaround.

- Create a new sheet.
- Then use CTRL-A to select all.
- Copy all cells
- Go to the new sheet
- Paste, and verify that this is acceptable and contains everything you need
- Delete the old sheet.

Answer (score 1):

TRY BELOW MY FIRST MACRO

```
Sub DELETE_all_PICS()
On Error GoTo booboo
For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Worksheet.Pictures.Delete
Next
Exit Sub
booboo: MsgBox "There is A problem."
End Sub
```