# I cannot select or interact with pictures taken with the excel camera

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365, bug

Though there are some similar questions, none restore full functionality or directly address excel camera pictures.

I am using the excel camera tool on office 365, windows 10.

After placing the image, I cannot edit, move, format or delete it.

I was able to delete it using the answer found here: https://superuser.com/a/885841/1195188

But this did not restore editing and moving functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is strange:

Immediately after placing the photo, resize or crop it. Afterwards, it behaves as you would expect an embedded image to. You are able to move, format, and delete it.

Weirdly, this also can solve the image quality problem. For whatever reason, excel changes the scale of the photo when you place it. Set the scale to 100%, then bump it up 1% at a time until the picture is "clean"